# Flutter Obfuscating android appbundle

Tags: android, flutter

Following the docs to publish an Android app I want to obfuscate my app as [recommended here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate#obfuscating-your-app). However

```
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
```

fails with the following error:

> Could not find an option named "obfuscate".
>
> Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter
>   commands and options.

Comment: Have you made sure that you have updated flutter and dart to latest version?